# How to check in nodemailer if an email could be delivered before trying to send it?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Is it possible to make some request to ensure that the email address really exists or that after sending it will return 250 OK response? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but going by the fact that most services require you to actually confirm your email, I'm guessing it's not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail servers often accept mail to non-existant addresses and then drop the messages or deliver these to catch-all addresses. This is used to make spamming harder – if all messages are accepted the spammer never knows which addresses are real and which are not.

So is dificult to really know if it exists or not.